# Atualizar dados em uma TextView automaticamente no Android Studio

Tags: php, android, android-fragment, localhost, textview

Estou montando um projeto onde preciso que meu aplicativo (feito no android studio) puxe dados de um servidor local e atualize automaticamente sem precisar de um botão de "refresh" ou um "swipe to refresh".

No momento que estou, consigo puxar os dados através de um script do php e mostrar no aplicativo, mas quando insiro um novo dado, ele não atualiza automaticamente, apenas se reiniciar o aplicativo.

Meu código php

```
$servidor='localhost';
$banco='measurer';
$usuario='root';
$senha='';


    $conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM medidas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        // output data of each row
        while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

           $json = json_encode($row);


        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo $json;
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

O java da minha activity no android studio

```
package com.example.lalam_000.introsliderexemple;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.ClientProtocolException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    TextView textView;
    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valor_vazao);

    new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

    return view;
    }

    private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context context;


    public GetTextViewData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new 
 HttpPost("http://192.168.0.101/teste.php");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        try {
            textView.setText(json.getString("vazao"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer um método de fazer um autorefresh onde os dados atualizariam sozinhos no aplicativo toda vez que um dado fosse acrescentado no banco de dados?

Comment: Opa amigo, boa noite, cara, com mysql é meio complicado de se fazer isso, pois ele não é um db em tempo real, teria que ser algo como firebase ou outro do msm tipo, com mysql o que você pode fazer é colocar algo pra fazer uma nova requisição a cada x tempo pra verificar se existe um novo dado

Comment: poderia me dizer como fazer isso? sou meio novo nessa área ainda

Comment: Cara, você pode deixar um service rodando ( O que gasta muita bateria) ou usar um JobScheduler: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8hbskNrKZU&t=1809s ou um AlarmManager: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHRKI3B_CwY, enquanto seu app estiver aberto, e quando ele fechar você faz o comando dos serviços pararem

Comment: Você pode colocar pra a "stopagem" de ser chamada no onDestroy

Comment: Mas no seu caso um service msm seria melhor porque esses outros que falei, demorar de reiniciar, se não me engano, o JobScheduler msm é no minimo a cada 15 minutos

Comment: Service: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EL1gLa4yl0&t=210s

Comment: vou dar uma conferida, obrigado!

Comment: cara, estava olhando o vídeo aqui, e estou meio perdido... você saberia me ajudar em como implementar o service no meu código?

Comment: mysql + android = [Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database)

Comment: I already did that